# How should python source distributions be structured so that tests can run?

Tags: python, testing, package

There are many posts on stackoverflow asking about directory structure for python projects. There are even some asking where test files should go. However, I have not found one which addresses the issue of actually running tests from a source distribution.

Suppose I have a python project called myproject. A source distribution would like something like this

```
myproject-source-dir
|README.txt
|LICENSE.txt
|NEWS.txt
|setup.py
|myproject
-|__init__.py
-|mymodule.py
```

Suppose `mymodule` defines a thing which I would like to make available when the user imports myproject:

```
# myproject/mymodule.py
def useful_thing(...):
    <do stuff>
```

I can make `useful_thing` available by importing it into the project name space in `myproject/__init__.py`:

```
# myproject/__init__.py
from myproject.mymodule import useful_thing
```

Once the project is installed so that myproject is in the system path, the user can do

```
import myproject
myproject.useful_thing(...)
```

so everything so far is nice and simple. Now suppose we add tests

```
myproject-source-dir
|README.txt
|LICENSE.txt
|NEWS.txt
|setup.py
|myproject
-|__init__.py
-|mymodule.py
|test
-|test_mymodule.py
```

`test/test_mymodule.py` surely wants to import useful things from mymodule

```
# test/test_mymodule.py
from myproject import useful_thing
```

or perhaps

```
# test/test_mymodule.py
from myproject import mymodule
```

The problem with this is that until the code is installed, `myproject` is not in the python system path so `from myproject import ...` doesn't work. That means that every time I want to run my tests, I have to first install the package. This seems wrong.

**Q:** What is the proper way to make tests runnable from a source distribution?

**note:** Whether the test directory is a subdirectory of `myproject-source-dir` or a subdirectory of `myproject` does not change the fact that `from myproject import ...` won't work out of the box.

Comment: This is a very old question but if somebody stumbles upon this they should know that the correct way of doing this is making your project a package and test it as it is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many source distributions I know of modify the module search path `sys.path` by adding the upper directory level relatively as a first item, in order to make Python find the source tree rather than an installed version of the module/application to test.

Consider this structure:

```
/test/
     test_app.py
/app/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
/README.txt
```

In `/test/test_app.py` you would import `app`:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
from app import Foo
```

and then test `Foo`. You might want to look at https://bitbucket.org/jgehrcke/gipc/src, this is where I used this idiom in quite a simple project.

Comment: Is this common/recommended? It smells funny to me.

Comment: @DanielSank It's pretty common in my experience.

Comment: As long as no other modules modify sys.path before you import your code to be tested, this method behaves predictable. As you can see, modification of sys.path is directly followed by the import. Hence, in the moment of import *in any case* your source tree is imported. So this method is reliable. Also, when some other party re-distributes your library/app, then the tests are usually not included, i.e. your sys.path modification will most likely not screw somebody else.